# Replace >, <, & chars that appear inside XML nodes

Tags: c#, xml

[Regular expression to match ">", "<", "&" chars that appear inside XML nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282614/regular-expression-to-match-chars-that-appear-inside-xml-nodes)

I have an almost indentical problem to this - however, I am using C#.

I'm not here to argue the validity of the XML.

What gets sent in is out of my control.

**Input XML:**

```
<PNODE> 
  <CNODE>This string contains > and < and & chars.</cnode> 
</PNODE>
```

**I need it to look like this:**

```
<PNODE> 
  <CNODE>This string contains &gt; and &lt and &amp; chars.</CNODE> 
</PNODE>
```

It looks like the guy found a solution for PHP- which doesn't help me.

However, I need to find a way escape the &, > and < characters inside the node, but leave the tag declarations alone.

Comment: In addition - since there seems to be some confusion: replace, htmlencode, securityelement.escape, xmltextwriter, etc - none of these common methods will work as they replace the node declaration tags as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Tidy.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/). It's a .Net implementation of Tidy.

Comment: While I'm sure I could find a .Net Tidy solution, which would hopefully work - is there another way to do this that doesn't require the Tidy Library or any other third party additions?

Comment: You could build your own implementation. This poorly formatted XML won't load into an XmlDocument, so you'd have to load it as a string, and automate a process to determine which items should be replaced, and which are a valid part of the document. Theoretically, any & could be replaced, and any > without a < before it, and any < with another < after it. Where any parser is going to run into problems will be cases like: `<PNODE><CNODE>This string contains <AND> and & chars.</CNODE></PNODE>` where the `<AND>` would be missed. From that you MIGHT be able to catch that the <AND> isn't closed...

Comment: Simply put, I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of .Net wrappers around the tidy library.

http://users.rcn.com/creitzel/tidy.html#dotnet

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/eftidynet.aspx

And there is a [.Net Port of tidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/).

Comment: While I'm sure I could find a .Net Tidy solution, which would hopefully work - is there another way to do this that doesn't require the Tidy Library or any other third party additions?

Comment: As mentioned by @md5sum, although possible to do on your own, why reinvent the wheel.  Do you have an underlying requirement where you can't use a 3rd party library / solution?  Especially like Tidy .Net since it's open source?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTTPUtility.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<text to Encode>");
```

Comment: This will destroy `<foo><bar>uh oh bad > < & characters</bar></foo>`; He needs to fix the bad characters without damaging `<foo>` and `<bar>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at SgmlReader:

http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader

It will give you exactly what you wants :) I use it here: http://www.xmltools.dk/HtmlToXml try it :) (you can disable the html tag and the uppercase-tags->lowercase-tags conversion.)

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used replace for XML (saves me having to bring in HTTP libraries):

```
string output = inputXml.Replace("&", "&amp;")
                        .Replace("<", "&lt;")
                        .Replace(">", "&tg;")
                        .Replace("'", "&apos;")     // optional
                        .Replace("\"", "&Quot;")    // optional
```

Comment: If he were goign to do this he should probably just use `HTTPUtility.HtmlEncode` but it's already been established that this won't work...

Comment: but this will affect your nodes as well.  I missed that part of your question.

Comment: inputXml is the *entire* xml. This will replace perfectly good XML along with the unwanted characters in the content.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not here to argue the validity of
>   the XML.

As with [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282614/regular-expression-to-match-chars-that-appear-inside-xml-nodes), the *right* answer is that what you got sent is *not* XML. It's a question of well-formedness, not a question of validity in the XML sense.

> What gets sent in is out of my control.

That may be true, but if someone sent you a quart of used motor oil and asked you to transform it into HTML, would you still accept it? Usually data interchange is done based on a contract (formal or informal), that the interchanged data will adhere to certain criteria. If it doesn't live up to the agreed-upon criteria, the data can be sent back, rejected.

If you're not requiring XML as input, this question is not about "<, & chars that appear inside XML nodes". Rather, it's about parsing SGML that looks a lot like XML, but which has < and & chars that appear in text content.

And to do that, .NET Tidy and SGMLReader are good solutions, as others have said.