# Replace >, <, and & chars that appear inside XML nodes

Tags: java, xml, regex

i have a problem similar to these ones described in these topics
1) [Replace >, <, & chars that appear inside XML nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720657/replace-chars-that-appear-inside-xml-nodes)
2) [Regular expression to match ">", "<", "&" chars that appear inside XML nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282614/regular-expression-to-match-chars-that-appear-inside-xml-nodes)

and I'm looking for a solution working in Java.
In practice I have a huge XML file (~5 MB) and I want to replace special characters with their respective entities (escaped characters), without changing the XML tag.
A tipical example should be:

```
<tag><anothertag>& < > </anothertag></tag> (before)
<tag><anothertag>&amp; &lt; &gt; </anothertag></tag> (after).
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to replace &lt; with < ? Why?? Also your before and after statements are identical.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you don't just use a CDATA block? By the way, I wouldn't use regex for this. @Philip: as far as I interpret the question, OP actually want to do it the other way round (i.e. make syntactically invalid XML syntactically valid). This is at least mentioned in title, links and code example.

Comment: Your explanation suggests you want to go `&lt;` to `<`, while your example shows the opposite transition. Can you clarify which you actually want?

Comment: Based on a response to 2, I'm not sure this is tractable: `<tag>Something<br/>Something Else</tag>` would convert to `<tag>Something&lt;br/&gt;Something Else</tag>` even if you accounted for nesting. I think you should fix whatever generates this code. (Thanks @BalusC )

Comment: XML is not regular language. It means: please, do not try to feed it into a regex. You will gain only pain.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse: the XML is generated from a remote node, not by me.
The file isn't indented and is very hard to read (due to size).
I was trying to indent it using Transform class, but I got several errors about the presence of some characters like "&", "<", ">".

Comment: @BalusC: sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: If you can, ask whoever is in charge of the remote node to fix the XML output.  This is really the preferred solution.  If there's no possibility of regenerating the huge XML document with correct escaping, then you will probably have to write a custom parser to fix the document.  You should not use the custom parser on any input except the specific broken data from this node, because it will do Bad Things to real XML from well-behaved services.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest that you don't use regular expressions to parse XML, and in this case, you shouldn't use regex at all.

What you need is a good XML parser/streamer framework, such as [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) or [StaX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) (due to the size of the file, I would go with the latter).

You would basically push each and every streaming event you read to a writer.

Once you identify a `characters` event while parsing the file with your reader instance, instead of directly writing it, you replace each symbol with its entity, and write the replaced `String` instead of the original one.

Note: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html) is an official **StaX** tutorial to get you started. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html) is the JEE5 reference page, which contains additional information.

**Why do that instead of applying a `Pattern` and parsing the whole file with a `BufferedReader`?**

- Because the performance would be awful (re-matching on the `Pattern` for each line of your 5MB file)
- Because your `Pattern` would have to be very complex (so, unreadable, and again, bad performance)

More SO documentation on regex XML parsing VS proper XML parsing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg?rq=1).

**Edit**

I haven't considered the case of a huge, entirely malformed XML file. 
In this case, a streamer framework might be impossible to use, since the file being streamed is **not** valid XML in the first place.

If you have exhausted every other choice, you want to pinch your nose shut, use a `BufferedReader`, and do something like this (needs a **lot** of elaboration - don't take it literally):

```
String killMe = "<element>blah < > &</element>";
// only valuable piece of info here: checks for characters within a node
// across multiple lines - again, needs a lot of work
Pattern please = Pattern.compile(">(.+)</", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher iWantToDie = please.matcher(killMe);
while (iWantToDie.find()) {
    System.out.println("Uugh: " + iWantToDie.group(1));
    System.out.println("LT: " + iWantToDie.group(1).replace("<", "&lt;"));
    System.out.println("GT: " + iWantToDie.group(1).replace(">", "&gt;"));
    System.out.println("AND: " + iWantToDie.group(1).replace("&", "&amp;"));
}
```

Output:

```
Uugh: blah < > &
LT: blah &lt; > &
GT: blah < &gt; &
AND: blah < > &lt;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one, because as far as I know the fact that there are tokens like >< as a part of the content of your XML, you have invalid XML. My best advice is to find a good xml parser like http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/ and hope it can handle your issues.