# How to replace < (&lt;) inbetween xml tags using regular expression?

Tags: php, xml, regex

I am fetching a xml data from database as a string.
    I want to **replace < with &lt ;** in between xml tags.For eg:

```
 <smallelement> a<b </smallelement>
```

To be replaced as

```
<smallelement> a &lt; b </smallelement>

i want to replace < with &lt;
```

If I use string replace function

```
  $content = str_replace("<","&lt;",$content);
it replaces element tag <smallelement> also like &lt ;smallelement.

   &lt;smallelement> a&lt;b &lt;/smallelement>
```

How can i achieve this using regular expression to replace content within xml tags or is there any other ways ?

Comment: Parse your xml first and then use [`htmlentities`.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: `<smallelement> a<b </smallelement>` isn't valid XML; you should store the XML with entities already replaced or enclose those contents with a CDATA area.

Comment: The thing is I am working on an already existing structure having numerous data in the above format. Hence I can't change it. So is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The data you are processing is ambiguous at best.  Is the scope always between the begin/end tags for `smallelement`, or is it between any begin/end tag pair?  Do you have to deal with anything other than `<`?  Could you have to deal with nested tag sequences such as `<xx> a < b <yyy> ddd </yyy> </xxx>`?  If it is tightly restricted, you may be able to cope — but it is ludicrous to have the database store malformed pseudo-XML in the first place.

Comment: Maybe this answer could also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2287467/1059457

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is not a perfect solution, but since you already have dirty xml, we can try a dirty solution, right? ;)

```
$content = preg_replace('@<(/?)([a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_-]*)>@', ':::$1$2;;;', $content);
$content = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $content);
$content = preg_replace('@:::(/?)([a-z0-9_][a-z0-9_-]*);;;@', '<$1$2>', $content);
```

1. Replace all `<xmltags>` with `:::tagnames;;;`
2. Replace all remaining `<` characters with `&lt;`
3. Replace all `:::tagnames;;;` with `<xmltags>` again

Again, this is far from perfect, but if you know which pseudo xml you have to expect, you may be able to work on it this way. Of course it will not work if you have strings like `:::sometext;;;` in your $content already.

Also the tags must contain of a-z0-9_- only.

Of course it would be better if you could use valid xml right way, but if you did, I think you hadn't asked this question.

Answer (score -1):

here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException {
        String str = "<smallelement> a<b </smallelement>";              
        String newstr = "";
        boolean flaQG = false;
        boolean flaQL = false;      
        int lastIL = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, String> al = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if(c == '<') {      
                flaQG = false;
                if(!flaQL) {
                    flaQL = true;
                }else {
                    al.put(lastIL, "<");
                    flaQL=false;
                }           
                lastIL = i;
            }else if(c == '>') {
                flaQL = false;
                if(!flaQG) {
                    flaQG=true;
                }else {
                    al.put(i, ">");
                    flaQG = false;
                }           
            }
        }

        Iterator it = null;     
        int j = 0;
        boolean check = false;
        //System.out.println("length  "+str.length());
        final CharacterIterator cit = new StringCharacterIterator(str);
        for(char c = cit.first(); c != CharacterIterator.DONE; c = cit.next()) {
            it = al.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {              
                 Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                 //System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
                 if((Integer)pairs.getKey() == j) {
                     check= true;
                     if(pairs.getValue().equals(">")) {
                         newstr += "&gt;";
                     }else {
                         newstr += "&lt;";
                     }
                 }
            }
            //System.out.println(c);    
            if(!check) {
                 newstr += c;
            }else {
                check = false;
            }
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(newstr);
    }
```

note: the above code wont work if your xml looks something like

```
 <smallelement> a<b=b>c </smallelement>
```

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't note that you asked for php solution, any way the logic is same, you should be able to implement the above logic in php, i hope.